# Can gestures pass through PageRouteBuilder?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using Navigator to push PageRouteBuilder as an overlay to my screen with opague set to false, so that it shows the route underneath it as well. But none of the gestures goes through the overlayed widget.

Using navigator for the overlay just removes so much hassle than using flutters own Overlay widget for it since it already contains all the functionality I need, but doesn't seem to let any gestures through.

Is there any way to make the gestures pass through my overlay?